# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have some issue with spring boot and hibernate I would like to inform you i'm very new to java.I have start writing a small program in java where I'm trying to fetch result from database using JPA while fetching result I'm got stuck with below error

Error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: DC_NOTIF_EVNT_ORG_CONFIG is not mapped [select count(*) from DC_NOTIF_EVNT_ORG_CONFIG C JOIN DC_NOTIF_EVNT_ORG_PERS B ON B.NOTIF_EVNT_ORG_CONFIG_ID=C.NOTIF_EVNT_ORG_CONFIG_ID JOIN GRR_PARTY GRR ON GRR.PERS_ID =B.PERS_ID   
JOIN DC_NOTIF_EVNT_CONFIG D ON C.NOTIF_EVNT_CONFIG_ID=D.NOTIF_EVNT_CONFIG_ID JOIN DC_SCHED_FREQ_CONFIG E ON E.SCHED_FREQ_CONFIG_ID= C.SCHED_FREQ_CONFIG_ID JOIN DC_NOTIF_EVNT_SCHED F
ON F.NOTIF_EVNT_SCHED_ID=C.NOTIF_EVNT_SCHED_ID JOIN DC_ORG G ON C.ORG_ID=G.ORG_ID WHERE C.ORG_ID=:orgId AND GRR.PERS_ID=:persId AND E.STRT_DT=:strtDt AND C.ACT_IND=1]
```

Code
main.java

```
    @SpringBootApplication
public class NotificationApplication {
           @Autowired
           private startTimeRepo repo;
           public static void main(String[] args) { 

                 SpringApplication.run(NotificationApplication.class, args);

                 List<Abc_Notification> es = repo.ifNotificationExst(dto.getOrgId(),dto.getUsers().get(0).getPersId(),dto.getScheduler().getStartDate());
                System.out.println(es);


           }
```

startTimeRepo.java

```
  package com.abc.dc.notification.dao;

    import com.abc.dc.notification.dao.model.Abc_Notification;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
    import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    import java.util.List;

    @Repository
    public interface startTimeRepo extends JpaRepository<Abc_Notification, Integer> {
        @Query(value = "select count(*) from DC_NOTIF_EVNT_ORG_CONFIG C JOIN DC_NOTIF_EVNT_ORG_PERS B ON B.NOTIF_EVNT_ORG_CONFIG_ID=C.NOTIF_EVNT_ORG_CONFIG_ID JOIN GRR_PARTY GRR ON GRR.PERS_ID =B.PERS_ID   
JOIN DC_NOTIF_EVNT_CONFIG D ON C.NOTIF_EVNT_CONFIG_ID=D.NOTIF_EVNT_CONFIG_ID JOIN DC_SCHED_FREQ_CONFIG E ON E.SCHED_FREQ_CONFIG_ID= C.SCHED_FREQ_CONFIG_ID JOIN DC_NOTIF_EVNT_SCHED F
ON F.NOTIF_EVNT_SCHED_ID=C.NOTIF_EVNT_SCHED_ID JOIN DC_ORG G ON C.ORG_ID=G.ORG_ID WHERE C.ORG_ID=:orgId AND GRR.PERS_ID=:persId AND E.STRT_DT=:strtDt AND C.ACT_IND=1", nativeQuery = true)
        List<Abc_Notification> orgnId(@Param("orgId") Long orgId, @Param("persId") Long persId, @Param("strtDt") LocalDate strtDt);

    }
```

Service Class: Abc_NotificationScheduleTimeService.java

```
package com.iqvia.dc.notification.service;

import com.iqvia.dc.notification.dao.model.Abc_Notification;
import com.iqvia.dc.notification.dao.startTimeRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class Abc_NotificationScheduleTimeService {

    @Autowired
    private startTimeRepo starttimeRepo;

    public Abc_Notification orgnId(Integer orgId){
        return  starttimeRepo.orgnId(abcorgIdId);
    }
    public Abc_Notification persIdn(Integer persId){
        return  starttimeRepo.persIdn(persId);
    }
    public Abc_Notification strtnDt(Integer strtDt){
        return  starttimeRepo.strtnDt(strtDt);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't access an instance variable from a static context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this part:

```
@Query(value = "select count(*) from ...", nativeQuery = true)
        List<Abc_Notification> orgnId(@Param("orgId") Long orgId, @Param("persId") Long persId, @Param("strtDt") LocalDate strtDt);
```

No mapping is done. The result type of query can be, for example, `Long` but not list of entities.

Comment: thanks for you prompt response after adding navtiveQuery it works but I'm not able to get count  and getting below error SQL Error: 17006, SQLState: 99999 Invalid column name

Comment: So it's another error. Wrong column is defined in your model. That's a different question. If you find this answer helpful, consider upvoting / marking as correct :)